# How to request JSON data in the viewDidAppear method or viewDidLoad?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsjsonserialization

If I call the `[self requestData];` from viewDidLoad my table populates itself with data just fine. If I move `[self requestData];` to the viewDidAppear method the table remains empty.

Also, I'm not entirely sure if     `[self.mainTableView reloadData];` is working. I'm trying to move the data request and handling to the viewDidAppear method because I saw that pattern in a code example and thought it might speed up my app launch somewhat. At the moment there's quite a lag from the app launch Default.png to the rootViewController.

thanks for any help with this.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [self requestData];
}



-(void)requestData {

    [HUD showUIBlockingIndicatorWithText:@"Fetching JSON"];

    NSError *requestError = nil;


    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL
                                                          URLWithString:kURL]];

    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&requestError];

    NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;

    if (requestError)
    {
        NSLog(@"sync. request failed with error: %@", requestError);
    }
    else
    {
        // handle data
        publicData =  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response
                                                                    options:0
                                                                      error:&jsonParsingError];
        publicDataArray = [publicData objectForKey:@"data"];

    }

    /*
     for(publicDataDict in publicDataArray) {
     NSLog(@"data output is %@",[publicDataDict objectForKey:@"title"]);

     }
     */
    [self.mainTableView reloadData];

        NSLog(@"reload table cat id %@", categoryString);

    [HUD hideUIBlockingIndicator];
}
```

Comment: You need to trace execution or add NSLogs to find out what's happening.  (But you will find that the data transfer is probably hanging you up -- you need to initiate an async data transfer as soon as possible, vs doing the sync transfer.  And don't do anything in viewDidAppear that you don't want repeated again and again and ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to optimise the wrong thing.

The reason you have a lag is that your url request is synchronous, so it is blocking the main thread while waiting for the data to be received. Using an asynchronous URL request will give you far better performance benefits that moving the loading call as you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidLoad` is the right place to make your JSON request because It is called once, and will keep data into memory.

`ViewDidAppear` is called each time view appear, it is not really made to retain object

The "lag" is the fact that your UI is not being responsive because the JSON post request is on the main thread.

Comment: `viewDidAppear:` is called just after the view appears on screen which is not the same thing as every time the user opens the app.

Comment: Nice of you to edit your answer to make the same point as I did.

Comment: When there is only one answer to a question, they can look similar ;)

Comment: And there are good reasons to load objects in viewWillAppear (which is earlier than viewDidAppear). Since views are not unloaded anymore, the appearance delegate methods are convenient places to load and unload resources in advance of removing them under memory pressure.

Comment: we're talking about JSON request here, would you place a POST request in `viewDidAppear` ?

Comment: I'm talking about your description of where the correct place to load objects is. I do my requests when the view loads, but I also do things asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` is called after the views have been created, but before they're drawn.

`viewDidAppear` is called after the views have been drawn. It's too late to set data here that affects the display. You could possibly load the data in `viewWillAppear`, but be aware that it may be called multiple times (e.g. switching between apps).

That's why setting data that affects the display works in `viewDidLoad`, but not `viewDidAppear`. `viewDidLoad` is called only once in a view controller's life cycle.

However, consider the user experience if your user's Internet connection is slow or the server is slow to respond. Your application will seem to "freeze" for awhile.

Instead of a synchronous request, consider using an asynchronous request. You could display a "loading" message, spinner, or something until the request returns, then update the UI directly.

Apple strongly recommends always making asynchronous requests when run from the main UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

to speed up launching try to load data asynchronously, like this:

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [self requestData];
}];
```

you shoud call it inside viewDidLoad